# getting email field two times if i select email address from user attributes in azure AD b2c

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

[image: getting email address textbox two times in Sign up and sign in (Recommended) flow.]Getting email address field twice in Sign up and sign in (Recommended) flow when select email address from user attributes and remove required verification from Social account sign up layout.

[image: if select email address attributes and removed required validation from Social account sign up layout then getting email textbox two times for local email login.]

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I want only one field for the email address in Sign up and sign in (Recommended) flow.
Added new screenshot in question.

Answer (score 0):

Deselect email address in User Attributes.

Follow this to disable email verification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/disable-email-verification?pivots=b2c-user-flow